# Excel spreadsheet - linking worksheets in one-many relationship

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Is it possible to link worksheets together in a one to many relationship based on row number?

The spreadsheet has basically two tabs, Header and Transactions.  One or many Transactions are linked to one Header record.  What I am looking for is some way to have the Header (Date, Desc) listed to the left of each transaction row.

An example might make this clearer: [Test1](http://associateddata.co.uk/Test/Test1.xlsx)

Ultimately, in that example, we might even seperate out the transaction worksheet into a number of seperate tabs, one for each 'Account'.

Thanks,

[image: Header]
[image: Transactions]

Comment: Use a screenshot instead. Many people are not going to open a file you link to because of the threat of viruses. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does the Sub-desc column uniquely specify the header? If so, you could use MID() to separate out "Desc x" and then use VLOOKUP() to fill in the Date and Desc columns. This doesn't help for the cases wher Sub-desc is blank..

Comment: No in reality the Sub-desc will contain various unrelated text.